# Do I need to use an "=" when using the ? : javascript shortcut?

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me if this is valid javascript to do this:

```
        if (wf.statusId == Status.Dirty) {
            wf.createdDate
                ? promises.push(self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key))
                : promises.push(self.wordFormAddSubmit(wf, key));
        }
```

Would there be cases where this would not work correctly if createdDate was not defined?

Here's what this replaced:

```
        if (wf.statusId == Status.Dirty) {
            if (wf.createdDate) {
                var updatePromise = self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key);
                promises.push(updatePromise);
            } else {
                var addPromise = self.wordFormAddSubmit(wf, key);
                promises.push(addPromise);
            }
        }
```

Also a related question.  Would it be possible to use the same syntax with ? : to replace the need for the if () { } construct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `=` with ternary operator is not mandatory unless `expr1` and `expr2` are returning something and you want to save it in some other variable.

In your case, unless `promises.push(self.wordFormAddSubmit(wf, key))` and `promises.push(self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key))` are returning something that you want to save it a variable, there is no need for a `=`.

Comment: Thanks. Could I replace the first "if" also with a ternary operator with a null action for the case where the status was not equal to dirty?

Comment: @SamanthaJ sorry, didn't understood `null action`. Please clarify

Comment: Best not to nest ?: it become impossible to maintain very quickly.

Comment: I was wondering how to remove the need for the if ( ) { }  now I am wondering.  Can I just combine the .forEach and .filter.  Would be interested to see if that's possible.  Don't know if I can have a .forEach and a .filter in the same statement.

Comment: @DavidBradshaw - Agreed, but is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
if (wf.statusId == Status.Dirty) {
    promises.push(self[wf.createdDate ? 'wordFormUpdateSubmit' : 'wordFormAddSubmit'](wf, key));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

wf.createdDate only true if it is not undefined or have value. so this should work fine.

```
if (wf.statusId == Status.Dirty) {
            wf.createdDate
                ? promises.push(self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key))
                : promises.push(self.wordFormAddSubmit(wf, key));
        }
```

Regards
Mk

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a ternary statement, using the conditional (ternary) operator, which by definition replaces an `if...else` construct.

From MDN:

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

[[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)]

Both of your code samples would work the same way, ie if `createdDate` was undefined the second expression of your ternary statement would run (the line after the `:`) just like the else block of your `if...else` construct would run.

The title question seems somewhat unrelated, in that you would only need to use `=` if you wanted to save a reference to something. In this case, it does not appear that you do.

As for your follow-up question, plenty of people use ternary statements for small checks and tasks that fit on one or a few lines (I personally don't because I prefer the readability of `if...else`), however anything even moderately complex can quickly make your code hard to read and understand. But yes, technically, ternary statements can replace `if...else` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the second question:

assuming you don't need to save the results in a variable, you can do:

```
 promises.push(wf.createdDate?  
            self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key) :
            self.wordFormAddSubmit(wf, key);
 );
```

and even this works:

```
 promises.push( 
      (wf.createdDate? self.wordFormUpdateSubmit:self.wordFormAddSubmit)(wf, key)           
     );
```

Comment: `(wf.createdDate? self.wordFormUpdateSubmit:self.wordFormAddSubmit)(wf, key) ` it lost the this context!